# Is there a 2D soft-body physics engine for Flash?

Tags: flash, physics, actionscript-3

I'd like to write a small physics game by using ActionScript, but do not want to write my own physics engine. Does anyone know a ready-to-use 2D soft-body physics engine with a Flash port?

Answer (score 1):

This one looks really good, based on Box2d.

http://code.google.com/p/quickb2/

I am currently dissecting the code for his top down car demo.